# How to conditionally render or toggle visibility in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to switch between components such that I have two component included in my App.js file

1. Login
2. Register

I have two button to trigger them but they are not changing instead i get this error on button click

```
TypeError: _this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState({
        screenwhich: false
      })', '_this.setState' is undefined)
```

This is my app.js file

```
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

// import axios from 'axios';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert,Button,TextInput ,TouchableWithoutFeedback,Image, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView,TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Register from './screens/Register';


export default function App() {
 


 state = {
   
   
  screenwhich:true,
  
 }


 
  const changeScreen = () =>{
    
   this.setState({screenwhich:false})
   
    
  }
 

  return (
    
    
      
      <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/background.jpg')} style={styles.background}>
<Text>Fha{state.screenwhich}</Text>     

     { state.screenwhich? <Login></Login>:
      <Register></Register>}
      
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./assets/logo-red.png')} />
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.login}  onPress={changeScreen}>
      <View style={styles.login}  >
      <Text style={styles.loginBtnTitle}>Login</Text>  
      </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight  style={styles.register} onPress={()=>Alert.alert("Registeration","Currently in Progress")  }>
      <View style={styles.register}  >
      <Text style={styles.registerBtnTitle} >Register</Text>  
      </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      
      
      
      </ImageBackground>
      
      
    
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:"center"
  },
  row:{
    display: "-webkit-box",
    display:" -ms-flexbox",
    display: "flex",
    
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    marginRight: "-15px",
    marginLeft: "-15px",

  },
  input:
  {
    
  display: "flex",
  width: "100%",
  // height:"50%",
  //  padding:50,
  fontSize: 20,
  lineHeight: 15.5,
  color: "#495057",
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  // WebkitBackgroundClip: "paddingBox",
  borderColor: "#ced4da",
  borderRadius: 0.25,
  // transition: "border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out",
  },
  background:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:"flex-end",
    alignItems:"center",

  },
  logo:{
    width:100, height:100, position:"absolute",top:100
  },
  login:
  {
    backgroundColor:"tomato",
    width:"100%",
    height:70,
    alignItems:"center"
  },
  register:
  {
    backgroundColor:"dodgerblue",
    width:"100%",
    height:70,
    alignItems:"center",
    
  },
  loginBtnTitle:{
    fontSize:30,
    top:20,
    color:"white",
    position:"relative"
  },
  registerBtnTitle:{
    fontSize:30,
    top:20,
    color:"white",
    position:"relative"
  }
});
```

When I click on login button i want to change value of screenwhich from true to false but it gives the mentioned error above

[image: The text above the buttons is from the respective component]

It should be changed as the button is clicked
I have to create forms in both register and login components later

Answer (score 1):

You have a function component and `this.setState` does not make sense here. It is only for class components. Change it to use `useState`

```js
export default function App() {
  const [screenwhich, setScreenwhich] = React.useState(true);

  const changeScreen = () => {
    setScreenwhich(!screenwhich)
  }

  // rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: also this syntax is new for me i wanted to ask how we would initialize a default value for screenwhich
lets say i originally wanted it to be false then how would i be able to do it

Comment: you just need to initilaze it to false when you set up useState. `const [screenwhich, setScreenwhich] = React.useState(false);`

Comment: Additionally, if you want to switch states, you basicaly use the existing state and change it. See my edit to follow that part.

Comment: Go through this documentation and you will get all the info you need on how to use it and good explanation of it as well https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Pls to not forget to mark as answer. I also noticed several answers popped up and they explain the same thing. However, pick the one you like the most and mark as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are using a `Functional Component` and trying to update the state with `this.setState()`. To manage state in a functional component, you will have to use the `useState` hook.

```js
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert,Button,TextInput ,TouchableWithoutFeedback, Image, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Register from './screens/Register';

export default function App() {
 
  const [screenWhich, setScreenWhich] = useState(true);
 
  const changeScreen = () =>{
    setScreenWhich(false);
  }

  return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/background.jpg')} style={styles.background}>

        { screenwhich ? <Login/> : <Register/> }

        <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./assets/logo-red.png')} />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.login}  onPress={changeScreen}>
          <View style={styles.login}  >
            <Text style={styles.loginBtnTitle}>Login</Text>  
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight  style={styles.register} onPress={()=>Alert.alert("Registeration","Currently in Progress")  }>
          <View style={styles.register}>
            <Text style={styles.registerBtnTitle} >Register</Text>  
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>      
      </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` only existed in class based component but you're using functional component instead. All you need to do is to change to class based component like below

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
 state = {screenwhich:true}

  changeScreen = () =>{
   this.setState({screenwhich:false})
  }
 

  render() {
      return (
        <View><Text>Testing</Text></View>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it gave me error that JSX  expressions must have one parent element
I understood what my mistake was though

Comment: @MohammadFahad: The error that you got has nothing to do with my solution, you can try out using my updated version, after which you can then slowly trace which of your component having structure problem

Answer (score 0):

Functional components are stateless!
You can't call `setState` within them.

You have the choice, turn your component into a class component (only recommended in a few cases... e.g. if you want to use it as HOC):

```js
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    state = {value: 1};
     this.updateState = () => this.setState({value: (this.state.value + 1)});
  const {value} = this.state;
  render() {
    return <div>
            <p>Hello class Component {value}</p>
            <button onClick={this.updateState}>Increment Value</button>
        </div>;
  }
}
```

Or go with Hooks (means `useState`):

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
 
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(1);


    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello functional Component {value}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setValue((value + 1))}>Increment Value</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```